# Unable to install apk in android emulator. App contains ARM native code

Tags: java, android

I downloaded an apk and tried to install it by dragging into the genymotion emulator. And got this error

```
An error occured while deploying the file.
This probably means that the app contains ARM native code and your Genymotion device cannot run ARM instructions.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download the zip file over here, drag the file into genymotion and run these commands. 
https://github.com/m9rco/Genymotion_ARM_Translation

```
  adb shell
  cd /sdcard/Download/
  sh /system/bin/flash-archive.sh /sdcard/Download/Genymotion-ARM-Translation.zip
  adb reboot
```

Comment: First we need to install a virtual device on Genymotion. Suppose it's *Samsung Galaxy S5*. Then the Arm-based AKP file should be dragged into it. Right?

Comment: yes you may do that too

Answer (score 15):

You need to install ARM translation on the emulated device:

- Download the right ARM translation archive for your device’s Android
  version. For Android 8, I used ARM_Translation_Oreo.zip. ([Download Link](https://github.com/m9rco/Genymotion_ARM_Translation/tree/master/package))
- Drag and drop the .zip file to the device’s unlocked screen and click
  on OK when asked for confirmation

Now you should be able to install any app even if it has ARM code.
**GoodLuck!**

Comment: Also, you have to get the play store app installed to get your apk recognized as such.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download Genymotion ARM Translation here https://github.com/m9rco/Genymotion_ARM_Translation
2. Drag and drop a zip archive to the your emuletor